# How to sync crontab with DirectAdmin backwards?

Tags: cron, directadmin

I have a few hundred cronjobs in DirectAdmin.

I need to string_replace every cronjob in DirectAdmin.

I managed to change all my cronjobs with crontab -e, so my cronfile in /var/spool/cron is now correct.

The problem is that in DirectAdmin only the old cronjobs reside.

My question is how to sync the string-replaced crons into DirectAdmin ?

So is there a way to read the changed /var/spool/cron-file into DirectAdmin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better not use  `crontab  -u  userfoo -e` to change your crons directly, because DirectAdmin will be unchanged.

This is better:

**Step1:** Open `/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/userfoo/crontab.conf`   and  **add “0=”, “1=”, “2=”**, etc. before every line:   (don't use this before a comment line):

```
1=1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/userfoo/domains/www.domfoo.nl/public_html/foo1.php

2=* 2 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/userfoo/domains/www.domfoo.nl/public_html/foo2.php
```

**Step2:** Go to DirectAdmin, cronjobs and click right-below on Save   (This will copy the crons to `/var/spool/cron/`)

All your crons will be active on-the-fly.